# angular 2 http request only after ngrx store check

Tags: angular, http, ngrx

my component has a subscription to a service which calls an api to get some values. Before the api call i want to check if my appStore has already those data to avoid a useless call but can't find a way to make it work.

How can i do it?

This is my component:

```
import { UserService } from '../../core/user.service';
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AnagraficaComponent implements OnInit {
  userData: any;
  constructor(private userService:UserService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUserData(1)
   .subscribe(result => {
     this.userData = result;
     });
   }
 }
```

And this is my service:

```
import { CURRENT_USER } from '../app.actions';
interface AppStore {
  currentUser: any;
}
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  currentUser: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private http: Http, private store: Store<AppStore>) {
    this.currentUser = store.select('currentUser');
  }
  getUserData(id: number): Observable<any> {
    // TODO: user store
    // check if there is a current user in store (means is already logged in)
    // if true return data from store

   /* 
   return this.currentUser
     .map(user => {
       return user;
     });
   */
   // else return data from server
   let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
   let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token);
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   return this.http.get(myGlobals.API_URL + 'user/' + id, options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      // TODO : check response
      // update store with current user from server
      // this.store.dispatch({ type: CURRENT_USER, payload: userData });
      return response.json().data;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just test like this:

```
import { CURRENT_USER } from '../app.actions';
interface AppStore {
  currentUser: any;
}
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  currentUser: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private http: Http, private store: Store<AppStore>) {
    this.currentUser = store.select('currentUser');
  }
  getUserData(id: number): Promise<any> {
     return new Promise<any>((resolve,reject)=>{

 let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

if(currentUser){
resolve(currentUser);
return;
}else{

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token);
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   return this.http.get(myGlobals.API_URL + 'user/' + id, options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.parse(response.json().data));
      // this.store.dispatch({ type: CURRENT_USER, payload: userData });
       resolve(response.json().data);
return ;
    });

}
});



  }
}
```

Comment: I need to check it against the store because it's a method i'm gonna use throughout the app and i would like to understand haw store works in ng app. Testing against the local storage it's not a desireable option.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a UserStore with a private behavior subject and expose observable of it publicly, then on each call you first check if you already have data in User subject if not only then call the service. And in the component level call thius store not the service

```
import { UserService } from '../../core/user.service';
export class UserStore {

    private _user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    constructor(
        private userService: UserService
    ) {
        this.loadInititalData();
    }

    get user() {
        return this._user.asObservable();
    }

    loadInititalData() {
        let user: User = this._user.getValue();
        if (!user) {   // only if value doesn't exist on the client
        this.userService.get()
            .subscribe(
            res => {
                this._user.next(res);
            },
            err => this.handleError(err, "loadinitialdata UserStore")
            );
        }

    }

    private handleError(error: any, src: string) {
        console.log(src + ": " + error)

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this, even though it sounds to me a bit overkilling to make a service which needs another service just to test a value in the store. I must say that i tested something similar in React and it looked a bit simpler, that's why i'm a bit surprised